# Why foreachRDD in Spark Streaming + Kafka is slow, should it be?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I am using Spark 2.1 and Kafka 0.08.xx to do a Spark Streaming job. It is a text filtering job, and most of the text will be filtered out during the process. I implemented in two different ways:

1. Do filtering directly on the output of DirectStream:

   ```
   val messages = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String, StringDecoder, StringDecoder](ssc, kafkaParams, topics)
   val jsonMsg = messages.map(_._2)
   val filteredMsg = jsonMsg.filter(x=>x.contains(TEXT1) && x.contains(TEXT2) && x.contains(TEXT3))
   ```
2. use the foreachRDD function

   ```
    messages.foreachRDD { rdd => 
              val record = rdd.map(_.2).filter(x => x.contains(TEXT1) &&
                                                    x.contains(TEXT2) &&
                                                    x.contains(TEXT3) )}
   ```

I found the first method is noticeably faster than the second method, but I am not sure this is the common case.

Is there any difference between method 1 and method 2?

Answer (score 1):

`filter` is a transformation.  Transformations are evaluated lazily, that is, they don't do anything until you perform an action, such as `foreachRDD`, writing the data, etc.

So in 1. actually nothing is happening, hence significantly faster than 2., which is using the action `foreachRDD` to do something.